# Variable declared inside template literal context problem

Tags: javascript, template-literals

This code works fine in the global context:

```js
console.log(`${text = "It works!", text}`);
```

But when you import it from another module (from html doc)

```
<script type="module" src="literal.js"></script>
```

or from another script

```
import "literal.js";
```

Then throw an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template literal is a red herring. `text = "It works!"` is sufficient to reproduce this problem.

```html
This will error:
<script type=module>
text = "It works!"
</script>
```

[Modules automatically run in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_modules) where [assigning to undeclared variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#changes_in_strict_mode) is an error instead of an implicit global.